# Error with Deleted Class, Expected Pattern/Declaration

Tags: ios, swift, compiler-errors

I seem to be getting a few errors with a class I deleted (moved to trash). Its not in my compile sources btw. The errors for the deleted class are:

```
Expected pattern
Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ";"
Expected declaration
```

Idk if the errors actually matter, cuz the class is deleted anyway so there is probably something else wrong with it. Also I tried remaking the class cuz it couldnt find it otherwise (because it was deleted) and the same errors still exist even tho the class is blank.

Comment: If you delete the project's derived data in the Projects Window, do you still get the error?

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and/or deleting derived data? That's my first go-to with these strange occurrences

Comment: Yeah thank you guys that worked